# get value in ObserableColection<> and process it?

Tags: c#, linq

Im new Linq in c# . I have a problem that needs to be solved. I add the values ​​to the ObserableColection. where there is count and price and i want to take those 2 values ​​and add it and write it in the function. Can anyone help me please.

my code :

```
public CookViewModel()
{
    cookviewmodel = new ObservableCollection<CookModel>();
    cookviewmodel.Add(new CookModel { Menu = "Bắp bò ngâm mắm nhĩ", PriceMenu = Utils.ConvertMoney("1000000"), Count = 2, DoStatus = "Hoàn tất", SumMoney = Sum() });
    cookviewmodel.Add(new CookModel { Menu = "Bắp bò ngâm mắm nhĩ", PriceMenu = Utils.ConvertMoney("1000000"), Count = 1, DoStatus = "Hoàn tất" });
    cookviewmodel.Add(new CookModel { Menu = "Bắp bò ngâm mắm nhĩ", PriceMenu = Utils.ConvertMoney("1000000"), Count = 1, DoStatus = "Hoàn tất" });
}

public double Sum()
{
    var count  = from f in cookviewmodel
                        select f.Count;
    var price = from p in cookviewmodel
                       select p.PriceMenu;
    
    return Convert.ToInt32(count) * Convert.ToDouble(count); 
}
```

I need to get the value of Count and PriceMenu and add them together

Class Utils :

```
class Utils
{
     public static string ConvertMoney(string value)
     {
         CultureInfo cul = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("vi-VN");
         return double.Parse(value).ToString("#,###", cul.NumberFormat); 
     }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem ? Or question ?

Comment: its question. I need change func Sum .

Comment: Do you want to get sum by each row or all sum? You try to get sum `SumMoney = Sum()`  one time, but the rest of the lines CookModel  haven't been added yet. `from f in cookviewmodel  select f.Count` will return IEnumerable<double> (many values, all values Count from cookviewmodel) but not one number

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this

```
internal class CookModel
{
    public string Menu { get; set; }
    public double PriceMenu { get; set; }
    public double  Count { get; set; }
    public double SumMoney => Count * PriceMenu;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, change your `PriceMenu` variable to be of numerical value (e.g. `double`) and not text (`string`), then you can use `Select` operator to map 'price multiplied by count';

```
totalCost = cookviewmodel.Select(vm => vm.Count * vm.PriceMenu).Sum()
```

ps. Maybe "ordersReceived" is a better variable name then "cookviewmodel" ?